# Compare string with values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, performance, comparison

I have a database containing the name of bands and other artists related to music. Now i want to check a string containing an artist name against this database and find similar or equal artists to avoid different kind of spelling.

I found the php function 'similar_text' and i am sure, it is no problem to build a script to do this comparison during a loop.

What would be the best and fastest way to do such a comparison?

Comment: is it a one time script? or a regular process (like daily, or weekly)?

Comment: The MySQL `soundex` function might be of use as well.

Comment: Everytime, a mp3-file is uploaded, the id3-tags get read and should be compared to the database.

'soundex' seems to be interesting. Is there a good article providing use-cases with a mysql database?

Comment: depending on your requirements, could you use a LIKE statement?

Comment: The LIKE statement only finds content that is like something, what i need is to find content that is similar to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the size of your data. if it's trivial [few tens of thousands] - then run nightly batch job that will:

- extract unique artist names from the source data
- calculate soundex
- create dictionary with key being soundex, value - list of the original strings for the artist column

at this stage you'll have to decide if you want automatical merging or manual approval for each rename. in the long run you can have helper table with proper spelling and found so far miss-spellings. those cases can be handled automatically the next time they are encountered.

if soundex is not good enough you can try to experiment with php's similar_text, levenshtein functions and compare names found in newly added data with 'approved' names of artists you've already reviewed earlier.

Comment: This sounds like an appropriate solution. I'll think about it and if nobody comes up with a better solution, i'll stick to yours. Thanks!

Comment: I guess, i will create a nightly script, that sorts the wrong artists out. Thanks for the help.